# Converting WebClient code to HttpClient code

Tags: c#, httpclient, webclient

I need help converting this WebClient to HttpClient code if it's possible, I will be really happy if it is.

I've been looking for something/someone that will convert it to me and I sadly didn't find anything.

Thanks!

```
    private void bunifuFlatButton9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                webClient.DownloadDataCompleted += new DownloadDataCompletedEventHandler(this.Complete);
                webClient.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri("https://www.bing.com/search?q=site:pastebin.com+" + this.textBox1.Text));
                webClient.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri("https://www.bing.com/search?q=site:pastebin.com+" + this.textBox1.Text));
                webClient.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri("https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Apastebin.com+" + this.textBox1.Text));
                webClient.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri("https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Apastebin.com+" + this.textBox1.Text));
                webClient.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri("https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Apastebin.com+" + this.textBox1.Text));
                webClient.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri("https://yandex.ru/search/?text=" + this.textBox1.Text));
                webClient.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri("https://yandex.ru/search/?text=" + this.textBox1.Text));
                webClient.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri("https://yandex.ru/search/?text=" + this.textBox1.Text));
                webClient.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri("https://yandex.ru/search/?text=" + this.textBox1.Text));
                webClient.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri("https://yandex.ru/search/?text=" + this.textBox1.Text));

            }
        }
    }

    private void Complete(object sender, DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MatchCollection matchCollection = Regex.Matches(new UTF8Encoding().GetString(e.Result), "(https:\\/\\/pastebin.com\\/\\w+)");
        int num = checked(matchCollection.Count - 1);
        int i = 0;
        while (i <= num)
        {
            using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(this.Complete2);
                webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(matchCollection[i].Value));
            }
            checked { ++i; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What are you having problems with.  This is a "question and answer" site, not a "we write your code for you" site

Comment: Which framework did u use? Netcore or NetFramwork? Which version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do something like this:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
List<string> urls = new List<string>();
urls.Add("https://www.bing.com/search?q=site:pastebin.com+" + this.textBox1.Text);
urls.Add("https://www.bing.com/search?q=site:pastebin.com+" + this.textBox1.Text);
//and so on...
foreach(var url in urls)
{
   client.GetAsync(url)
           .ContinueWith(async (T) => {
                 string result = await T.Result.ReadAsStringAsync();
                 OnComplete(result);
            });
}
```

Then:

```
public void OnComplete(string result)
{
  //todo: convert your result to utf-8 and so on...
}
```

You can do some exception handling inside ContinueWith block to prevent errors.

Comment: Dear you should add this package for using ReadAsStringAsync extensions method: 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http.Formatting

Comment: You can initialize your list of URLs using the collection initialization syntax: `var urls = new List<string> { $"http://whatever1/?q=pb+{textBox1.Text}",  $"http://whatever2/?q=pb+{textBox1.Text}" };`